# Is this a correct use for display:flex?

Tags: html, css, width, flexbox

Is this a correct use case?

Display: flex on a `<ul>`, and then every `<li>` has either a pixel or percentage based width.

The main reason I want to use it is so that I can utilise `align-items: center` (vertical alignment).

It seems to work well, and I can't get it working this nicely with anything else, but it feels wrong because I'm not actually using any flex values on the list items.

Comment: Using `align-items: center` for vertical alignment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that use is perfectly valid. It just means all the children get their default behaviour, which is `flex: 0 1 auto` (syntax is `flex: <flex-grow> <flex-shrink> <flex-basis>`). And that happens to do what you want, which is simply align all the items appropriately. You don't want any items to grow (`flex-grow: 0`), they should all shrink to equal sizes (`flex-shrink: 1`) if necessary to fit and you want them laid out according to the content (`flex-basis: auto`).

I recommend going through the following page, because it explains it quite clearly: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

It explains all the attributes, has examples and links to the most crucial W3 resources when necessary, such as http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/images/rel-vs-abs-flex.svg for `flex-basis`.